# How to access a session variable in a .js file in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp

In my [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) application I am creating a session variable in some controller, which I need to access in a ".js" file. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Why, exactly?  Session variables are designed to be *only* server-side.

Comment: Agreed, session variables, or any server side variables should not be handled/accessed directly in client side code. I feel better to pass them like I have done in my answer

Comment: strager, sandeepan: so you are saying that when i save the users name in the session im not allowed access to that data client side?

Comment: @dogmatic when did I say you are not allowed to or you should not access server side data in client side? Of course you should. Just pass the things you need as function parameters to make your client side script, (i.e. javascipt) separate from server code (i.e. inline server variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest passing them as parameters like this -

```
<a onclick="some_function('<?php echo $_SESSION['var'] ?>')">Click</a>
```

and have the javascript function `some_function()` process it instead of assigning them inline. This way you can have the javascript file free from server side code. This is the cleanest way.

I too feel that because session variables are server side, they should not be handled directly in client side language through inline code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">var myVar = '<?php echo $this->Session->read('some_var'); ?>';</scritp> no need to have functions and onclicks all over the place

Comment: @dogmatic no need to have functions and onclicks and downvote? give some justification to support your point. Did you understand what I am explaining in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically generate your JS file so that it contains the value you want. You can set up your server to parse `.js` files through PHP, or you can just name the JS file `.php`:

```
var myVar = '<?php echo addslashes($_SESSION['myVar']); ?>';
```

Comment: is the mixing of PHP code in js good from a coding standard point? Is it not better to have js files separate and pass parameters to js functions if server side values are needed instead of doing this?

Comment: @sandeepan: Sure, I was going to suggest an inline script initially, but edited my answer only because the OP mentioned a .js file.

Comment: using $_SESSION directly when you have the session helper is not best practice. using php to push assets is worse, its a million times slower and what happens when the browser caches it, or you going to disable that also.

Comment: @dogmatic69: I'm not familiar with CakePHP, and I'm guessing that's the session helper you're talking about. Also, I'm just answering the OP's question - it's not that I recommend doing this.