# Passing dynamic parametes to js code - which is better practice?

Tags: javascript, code-generation, dynamic

For passing dynamic values to js code, is it better to do like this?

```
var myVar = '<?php echo addslashes($_SESSION['myVar']); ?>';
```

Or make an AJAX call at run time to get the session variable and assign it to myVar?

What are the pros and cons?

I personally prefer the AJAX method. It makes the code look better in case of complex array assignments etc.

Would like to get expert opinions.

**Updates**

I understand that using the AJAX method, every http request counts. But if we have well defined functions inside the javascript files, we would only need to have the function parameters available. And the parameters can be passed in the function calls whenever we want to call them, e.g. like this:-

```
<a onclick="some_function('<?php echo $_SESSION['var'] ?>')">
```

This is how I normally do and in my project I rarely need to pass them inline in javascript files. And I have AJAX calls for doing server side processing (of course when it is needed).

The basic idea I have here is to have separate js files intead of inline js scripts. I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231488/how-to-access-a-session-variable-in-js-file-in-cakephp). I would definitely not make an AJAX call for fetching each and every variable (as it may look like from my question) because such a situation would not arise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AJAX call is another request, and the results will not be immediately available -  writing dynamic data inline is available straight away. In this case, I would tend to choose the inline approach.

PHP's `json_encode()` might make it relatively easy to write out even huge arrays without cluttering the code much.

Comment: I actually didn't mean to do an AJAX request for fetching each and every server side variable to be used in the javascript. Please check my update.

Comment: @sandeepan I see your point about having separate JS scripts, and it makes sense - it's the cleanest way. I personally would probably still tend to put the dynamic bits into the document's `<head>` but I'd say both approaches are all right

Comment: do you mean dynamic bits in the js code in the document's head? But is that unavoidable in your case? Do you accept that you are not following the cleanest way? :)

Comment: @sandeepan yes. The point against is that the Ajax method creates an additional request for every page request, I'm not sure whether I would like that. But I'm undecided: Your method is definitely the nicest way to deal with dynamically changing JS data, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you are not actually generating Javascript code dynamically; You are using PHP to pass the value of an argument to the browser.

If this is the only (or the main) functionality of PHP in your code, it is better to use AJAX, and not generate the page itself using PHP (i.e., use a .html file instead of .php).  Reason: Works faster, as most of the content is stored statically.

If you use PHP to generate most of the page, there is no need to add another request, as Pekka mentioned.  Just inline it.

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables you are correct... edited the title. Please check my question update. Thanks

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables I was wrong to say I would prefer AJAX calls for assigning dynamic parameters and think it is not wise to have AJAX calls because every ajax call causes an additional request. If passing dynamic parameters is the main requirement, doing it like I wrote in my question update would be better. An AJAX request is not needed in this case unless there are server side tasks.

Comment: @Sandeepan: Do you use PHP for anything else other than session management?

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables yes for everything, not only session management - like everybody does.

Comment: @Sandeepan: In this case, the use of AJAX just for fetching the session content is redundant.  Why not have PHP write the content of the session into a Javascript object in a global var, and call "some_function(session.var)"?

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables - yes redundant, that's why. But again, are global variables advisable? They also aren't good practice.

Comment: IMHO a global page-scoped variable makes more sense then mixing inlined PHP and Javascript all over the place.  Language injection is a poor habit.

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables  - yes agreed that global variables make more sense than inlined way. But I am neither favoring globals, nor inlined way. I am rather favoring passing variables as function parameters.